# How does electronic first curtain shutter match the second curtain?

Tags: shutter, second-curtain, rolling-shutter, electronic-shutter

I previously [incorrectly
understood](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109689/why-is-flash-sync-speed-much-slower-than-flash-duration) how the shutter curtains work. I thought they move at so high
speed that e.g. at 1/4000 s shutter speed, the first curtain first opens very
quickly, the shutter is open for 1/4000 s and the second curtain closes very
quickly.

However, I was recently told that at 1/4000 s shutter speed, the curtains move
really slow and there is only a small moving slit between the first and second
curtains.

My camera, a Canon EOS RP, however, has electronic first curtain shutter.  The
second curtain is mechanical.

How does this electronic first curtain shutter actually work?

My first understanding of it was simply that it globally connects all of the
CMOS photosites to ground (so all pixels have the RST line active
using the terminology of
[Wikipedia's CMOS sensor page](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Aps_pd_pixel_schematic.svg)),
and then the RST is deactivated simultaneously across the whole
sensor area.

However, if the second curtain is moving slowly, obviously the first curtain
has to be moving slowly too.

So, my current understanding is that the RST lines are first
active, and then gradually deactivated on a row-by-row basis, so that the row
where reset is to be deactivated moves exactly at the same rate as the
mechanical second curtain moves.

Is this current understanding correct? I think this current understanding would
avoid the severe rolling shutter effect of electronic second curtain. The only
problem would be to match the movement of the electronic first curtain very
accurately to the movement of the mechanical second curtain.

This current understanding would also explain why the second curtain is
mechanical, i.e. CMOS photosites have no way to be stopped while maintaining
the current charge, apart from covering them with a mechanical curtain, and you
can't read the whole sensor area in few milliseconds.

Comment: See also: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39489/disadvantages-of-electronic-first-curtain-shutter

Comment: So what is your question (beyond the answer you already put into the question)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no global reset on all pixels simultaneously. This is the Holy Grail of sensor design that hopefully may come soon.
Canon, in order to save cost, does *not* include a mechanical first curtain in your RP.
Electronic first curtain is just a row by row read that ignores the result by dumping the charges. That row will start accumulating charges again.  That is how exposure starts.  The mechanical second covers the sensor so that the pixels can be read out in leisure.  Because the first curtain ignores the readout, it can "move" at the same speed as the second mechanical curtain, at ~1/200 sec from bottom to top of the picture.
Full electronic shutter, the second curtain must read and convert the pixels to digital.  It is a lot slower than mechanical curtains.  No camera makers specify how slow their electronic shutters are.  They are probably a lot slower than 1/30 sec with a much narrower "slit".

Answer (score 1):

I think if you read the manual you will find that the electronic first curtain/mechanical second curtain function is only available at SS's below shutter curtain transit time/flash sync (~ ≤ 1/250). And at higher SS's it is functioning as a completely electronic shutter... which is rolling readout, not global.

The rolling readout electronic shutter works by activating/deactivating/reading lines in sequence, simulating the slit opening of a fully mechanical shutter. It is basically recording one frame of video/live view output.

Comment: How does that apply to other cameras (eg Sony a6000) in which half the shutter noise is always heard even at high speeds?

Comment: IDK what you mean by "half the shutter noise." On a mirrorless camera you can have up to three types of shutter function... silent (rolling readout), electronic first curtain, or fully mechanical (slit). 
The fully mechanical shutter is required to sync with flash and to eliminate the rolling shutter effect (warping). But you won't have the "other half" of the noise common with a DSLR, which is the mirror slap.
AFAIK, the Sonys all have a fully mechanical shutter capability. Apparently the EOS RP does not.

Comment: What I meant is, unless this is Canon specific, why are eg Sony cameras (unless it is a model featuring full electronic shutter) not silent at any speed?