# Nikon D5100 half bright-half dark image with horizontal thin black line

Tags: nikon, dslr, troubleshooting, sensor

I am getting half bright-half dark image with horizontal thin black line on my Nikon D5100. Does anyone has any idea ? i am extremely worried. Warranty just expired. I have sample images uploaded at flickr (link below). i also attached my last good photo that i took few hours earlier. thanks a lot in appreciation.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/sumandutta/

Comment: Damaged sensor.

Comment: Did you use the flash? If, so you may be shooting above the sync-rate.

Comment: i also think its due to something wrong in the sensor. I checked all possible modes that i used to take photos (few hours earlier i used the same settings, modes) Coincidentally the lens is also making some minor noises during focus and i have only one now with me so not sure.

Comment: @Itai - Check [this one](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sumandutta/11692642345/) out. See the purple color with vertical lines? See the black horizontal line with a single red pixel ending it and how the line then continues in light grey? See how the bright area starts at the same position as in the other samples? Not a chance it be the effect of flash off-sync.

Comment: The black line can be also caused by some conducting debris close to the sensor shorting the fetch lines. Check it out very carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Approaching this kind of problem is a process of elimination.

Initially Flash sync seems most likely but the effect would be across a landscape frame.  It also happens when the flash is not in use.  So whatever it is happens in-camera and is not mechanical.

Any kind of lens issue would neither be as straight as those displayed nor as consistent.

After that it's something electronic... Anything in the digital domain would yield a binary failure (any effect would have a sharp edge.)

That leaves the only optical analogue component which is either the sensor itself or that the a/d converter is at fault.

You could do further testing, try looking at 'Live View' for example and see if the problem exists there but realistically whatever it is beyond what you know currently is not going to be fixable without the camera taking a visit to the service centre.

By 'just expired' if we're talking a few weeks then in many territories the manufacturer will honour the warranty as a goodwill gesture.  Give it a try.

Comment: Yes in the live view also same problem exists. exactly as in the images in daylight and or night. I forgot to mention this crucial point. warranty expired 47 days ago. Originally the camera was bought in korea now im in thailand. This Saturday will take it to the service center. Lets see what they suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Went to nikon service center. The problem is due to the damaged sensor. Confirmed !!. It was due to direct laser light on sensor. Happened during video/photo capture on 31st night, new year celebration in Bangkok. The video...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKyID1SCLz0