# Uneven exposure with Sony a35 - one side of image much lighter than the other

Tags: exposure, troubleshooting, sony

My camera Sony a35 all of a sudden started taking photos with one side lighter then the other - almost white. And it's worse with outdoor settings. I have tried cleaning the lens filter and that hasn't helped. Please help!
It seems to cut the photos in half and make one side brighter then the other, it's a lot worse in out door settings. Where it is more brighter. I thought maybe the image sensor but not sure I cleaned it we'll.

Comment: Can you post an example? Or, ideally, several examples in different situations?

Comment: Note that if you vote down the question, the asker will not have the reputation required to embed a photo.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you take the lens off?

Comment: Shutter broken?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear - without some example photos, we're just guessing here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what looks like [a similar problem](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46442/nikon-d5100-half-bright-half-dark-image-with-horizontal-thin-black-line) on a Nikon D5100. It sounds like the culprit is a damaged sensor, possibly due to laser light.