# Why does turning on flash cause a change in exposure

Tags: exposure, hotshoe-flash, live-view, nikon-z6

I bought my first flash unit (Godox) and I am trying to understand how it works.
Here’s what I don’t understand: when I look at the live view on my Nikon Z camera I have see an underexposed scene. The live view is very dark.

If I now turn on the flash, the live view immediately becomes brighter (exposed better).

Why is that? I can tell that neither ISO, shutter speed or aperture changed. Only the histogram shifts to the right significantly.
So what changes when I turn on the flash?

Surely a basic question, maybe someone can enlighten me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Nikon, but probably the live view display has a setting to enable/disable something like "shot result preview". Check your manual - search for the phrase "apply to live view" which my googling indicates could be relevant - and post as an answer here, if you discover the explanation.

Comment: I use Canon, when shoot in manual with a flash in the dark, you're not going to see anything in the lcd, so live view will auto turn up the iso so you can see something on the screen. It does not do anything to your image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: The exposure isn't changing; the exposure *simulation* in liveview is being turned off.

Whenever you take a flash image, you're basically combining two different exposures from two different sources of light: the ambient (all the light in the scene that isn't from the flash) and the flash. And these two exposures can be at different levels, because they rely on different settings. Ambient exposure is determined by iso, aperture, and shutter speed. But flash exposure is determined by iso, aperture, power, and flash-to-subject distance.

On any camera the metering system can only measure the light that's in the scene. A flash burst isn't in the scene yet while you're composing, so the exposure system/simulation can't account for it. *It can **only** show you the ambient portion of the exposure.*

If you have your iso, aperture, and shutter speed set to underexpose the ambient (or [kill it](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18537/what-does-it-mean-to-kill-the-ambient)), then that's what exposure simulation in liveview is going to show you: a very underexposed image.

Your camera has been programmed to understand this is a very common scenario with flash, so as soon as a flash is sensed, exposure simulation is turned off; and the scene in liveview is simply displayed so you can best see what you're doing (i.e., the camera ignores the exposure settings and just treats the image as if the settings let the ambient be well-exposed at "0").

Some cameras do not do this, and you have to manually turn off exposure simulation to see what you're doing in the viewfinder with flash.

Comment: For Nikon Zf/Z8/Z9 it is menu item d9 View Mode (Photo Lv). By default it is set to "Show effects of settings" > "Only when flash is not used". It can also be set to "always" or "adjust for ease of viewing". The Z6/Z7 only have d8/d9 "Apply Settings to Live View" and only settable to "On" or "Off"... so it's not one of those.