# Picture I take in low light using yougnuo 580ex comes out like this that its upper bright becomes bright and lower comes out to be totally black?

Tags: image-quality, camera-settings

How to take proper picture by using external flash?what is the mistake I did in capturing picture I'm a noob in photography
I have nikon d5300

Comment: Can you provide some example image? What speed do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my camera limited to a shutter speed of 1/250th when the flash is up?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22712/why-is-my-camera-limited-to-a-shutter-speed-of-1-250th-when-the-flash-is-up).

Comment: Can you please clarify what flash you're using? Yongnuo does not make a 580EX, but Canon does. Maybe also see: [Is flash brand X compatible with camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100131)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using too high a shutter speed. Consult the manual for your external flash and use the shutter speed which is supported by your external flash.

Comment: The shutter sync speed limit is from the camera body, not from the flash.